# How to split POST array in groups?

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array, transpose

I need each value of each array add on new array like person.

```
<div class="person">
    <input name="name[]">
    <input name="type[]">
</div>
<div class="person">
    <input name="name[]">
    <input name="type[]">
</div>
```

Could be two persons how also ten o more is dynamic.

$_POST return that:

```
Array( [name] => Array([0] => oliver [1] => tom) [type] => Array([0] => developer [1] => designer) )
```

I want something like that the two persons separate, but i fail trying:

```
$person1 = array(
"name" => "oliver"
"type" => "developer"
)

$person2 = array(
"name" => "tom"
"type" => "designer"
)
```

Comment: It appears that the `$_POST` return value is two parallel arrays, one of "names" and one of "types", where your created arrays are one per "person".

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$arr['type'] = $_POST['type'];

array_unshift($arr, null);
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_map', $arr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Oliver
            [1] => developer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tom
            [1] => designer
        )

)
```

Comment: like `array_unshift($_POST, null); print_r(call_user_func_array('array_map', $_POST));`

Answer (score 1):

Group your input elements and letting PHP create the arrays for you!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>";
}

?>
<form method="post">
  <div class="person">
      <input name="person[0][name]" value="Fred">
      <input name="person[0][type]" value="Developer">
  </div>
  <div class="person">
      <input name="person[1][name]" value="Alex">
      <input name="person[1][type]" value="Designer">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/syv-xw9

Comment: This is a good solution however it will involve a lot of clientside overhead when adding/deleting people dynamically having to update all indexes.

Comment: @Starx imeant the numerical indexes.. 0,1,2 these will all have to be controlled in javascript to not create gaps in the php later on

Comment: @YotamOmer It works without too, I've updated the answer. You point is still valid though - Anyone with allot of form elements is going to have a headache I think.

Comment: @AlexP using `name="person[]['name']"` in your inpunts will not work. update your phpFiddle to check. If it did work it would have been the best answer :)

Comment: @AlexP this will not work - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/778-9hs . the output is `[person] => Array([0] => Array([name] => Fred)[1] => Array([type] => Developer)[2] => Array([name] => Alex)[3] => Array([type] => Designer))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$people = array(); // define new array

// first loop to find the minimal size array - this will prevent errors down the road.
$minIndex = 0;
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    if(is_array($value)){
        $currentSize = sizeof($value); // get the current data array length
        if(($minIndex==0) || ($minIndex > $currentSize))
            $minIndex = $currentSize; // finds the minimus array length
    }

//populate the $people array
for($i = 0; $i < $minIndex; $i++){ // loop until $minIndex to prevent errors
    $current = array(); // this is the current person
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) // loop through all $_POST arrays
        if(is_array($value)) // only if this is an array
            $current[$key] = $value[$i]; // add the current data to the current person

    array_push($people,$current);
}

print_r($people); // print all people
```

For your example this will print:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array([name] => oliver [type] => developer) 
    [1] => Array([name] => tom [type] => designer)
)
```

So you can reach person's details like this: `$people[0]['name']`, `$people[0]['type']`, etc..

Comment: The problem is the arrays could be more than name and type, could be twenty o more just for the example put two.

Comment: This should now work, I have only one more trick to do with indexes which I will update in a sec

Comment: I need insert on table each name and each value of each array

Comment: @alejandrosanabria I've now tested it on my local machine, It works perfectly. also, as I told Starx the foreach($_POST) runs only twice.. Meaning it has the same (low) efficiency.

Comment: Thank you yotam i have a solution better with this <input name="person[][name]" value="Fred"> but also thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many names and types you have, feeding the two associative arrays into `array_map()` will restructure / transpose your data as desired.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JJfZT))  (or if you need associative keys in the subarrays: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/2ViBK))

```
var_export(array_map(function($n, $t){return [$n, $t];}, $_POST['name'], $_POST['type']));
```

For example:

```
$_POST = ['name' => ['oliver', 'tom'], 'type' => ['developer', 'designer']];
```

becomes:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'oliver',
    1 => 'developer',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tom',
    1 => 'designer',
  ),
)
```

and

```
$_POST = ['name' => ['oliver', 'tom', 'mitchel'], 'type' => ['developer', 'designer', 'artist']];
```

becomes:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'oliver',
    1 => 'developer',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tom',
    1 => 'designer',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'mitchel',
    1 => 'artist',
  ),
)
```